# How to use cursor with parameters in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, parameters, cursor, error-correction

Cursor I'm using is...

```
Create Proc GetExamResults (@Course_Id varchar(100), @Semester varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @subjname varchar(100)  
    declare @subjects varchar(7000)  
    declare @subjectsselection varchar(7000)  
    declare @SumSelection varchar(7000)  
    declare @NoOfSubjects int
    set @NoOfSubjects = 0

    set @subjects = ''  
    set @subjectsselection = '' 
    set @SumSelection = ''

    DECLARE subject_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT distinct Subject_Name FROM Exam_Result where course_id = @Course_Id And Semester = @Semester 

    OPEN subject_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
    INTO @subjname  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        set @subjects = @subjects + '[' + @subjname + '],'  
        set @subjectsselection = @subjectsselection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0)) As [' + @subjname + '],' 
        set @SumSelection = @SumSelection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0))+' 

        set @NoOfSubjects = @NoOfSubjects + 1

        FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
        INTO @subjname  
    End  
    CLOSE subject_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE subject_cursor;  

    select @subjects = LEFT(@subjects, LEN(@subjects) - 1)  
    select @subjectsselection = LEFT(@subjectsselection, LEN(@subjectsselection) - 1)  
    select @SumSelection = LEFT(@SumSelection, LEN(@SumSelection) - 1)  

    print @subjects  
    print @subjectsselection  
    print @SumSelection

    declare @query nvarchar(4000)  

    set @query = 'select S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, ' + @subjectsselection + ',' 
    set @query = @query + 'Exam_Type,' + @SumSelection + ' As Grand_Total, '
    set @query = @query + '(' + @SumSelection + ')' + '/' + convert(varchar(10),@NoOfSubjects) + ' As Avg'
    set @query = @query + ' From '  
    set @query = @query + '(select Enroll_Number, Student_Name, Course_Id, Semester, Subject_Name, MarksObtained, Exam_Type from Exam_Result ) ps '  
    set @query = @query + ' pivot(sum(MarksObtained) for Subject_Name in (' + @subjects + ')) as pvt'  
    set @query = @query + ' inner join Stud_Info S on S.Enroll_Number = pvt.Enroll_Number '
    set @query = @query + ' where pvt.Course_Id = ''' + @Course_Id + ''' and pvt.Semester = ''' + @Semester + ''''
    set @query = @query + ' group by S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, Exam_Type'
    print @query
    exec sp_executesql @query  
end
```

These 2 tables are used in cursor...

1] **Stud_Info**

```
CREATE TABLE Stud_Info
(Enroll_Number       varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
Salutation           varchar(10) NULL,  
First_Name           varchar(20) NULL,  
Middle_Name          varchar(20) NULL,  
Last_Name            varchar(20) NULL,  
Course_Id            varchar(20) NULL,  
Batch                varchar(20) NULL)

INSERT into Stud_Info values(11161,'Mr.','Mack','B','Botha','MECH','Batch1');    
INSERT into Stud_Info values(11162,'Mr.','John','A','Los','CIVIL','Batch2');    
INSERT into Stud_Info values(11163,'Ms.','Merry','F','Dsuza','ELCT','Batch1');    
INSERT into Stud_Info values(11164,'Mr.','Pow','B','Janero','MECH','Batch2');    
INSERT into Stud_Info values(11165,'Mr.','Martin','J','Smith','MECH','Batch1');
```

2] **Exam_Result**

```
CREATE TABLE Exam_Result
(Result_Id               numeric(18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
Enroll_Number            varchar(50) NULL,  
Student_Name             varchar(100) NULL,  
Course_Id                varchar(50) NULL,  
Semester                 varchar(50) NULL,  
Subject_Id               varchar(50) NULL,  
Subject_Name             varchar(50) NULL,  
MarksObtained            int NULL,  
Exam_Type                varchar(50) NULL)

INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'Mack','MECH',1,'MT','Maths',25,'Internal1');  
INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'Mack','MECH',1,'EN','English',22,'Internal1');  
INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'Mack','MECH',1,'SC','Science',20,'Internal1');  
INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'MACK','MECH',1,'MT','Maths',21,'Internal2');  
INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'Mack','MECH',1,'EN','English',24,'Internal2');  
INSERT into Exam_Result values(11161,'Mack','MECH',1,'SC','Science',22,'Internal2');
```

Here I'm passing it with 2 parameters suppose I'm passing `GetExamResults 'MECH','2'`

Then result comes like...

```
Enroll_Number  Student_Name Course_Id   Semester  Maths    English    Science    **Exam_Type**    total      avg

11161          Mack          MECH         1         25        22          20      **Internal1**      67        total/all sub
11161          Mack          MECH         1         21        24          22      **Internal2**      67        total/all sub
```

But I want to trace (through adding 3rd parameter for Exam_type) with `Exam_Type`... and look in for result something like.....

When user execute `GetExamResults 'MECH','1','Internal1'` then result should come like...

```
Enroll_Number  Student_Name Course_Id   Semester  Maths    English    Science    **Exam_Type**    total      avg

    11161          Mack          MECH         1         25        22          20      **Internal1**      67        total/all sub
```

and when user execute `GetExamResults 'MECH','1','Internal2'` then result should come like...

```
11161          Mack          MECH         1         21        24          22      **Internal2**      67        total/all sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. I've added an optional parameter @Exam_Type. If you do not specify value, or set null, procedure will return all rows.
Cursor definition changed to include LOCAL and FAST_FORWARD to speed up execution. `And (@Exam_Type is null OR @Exam_Type = Exam_Type)` added to filter exam_results by value of @Exam_Type; if null, no filtering occurs. The same filter is added to `(select Enroll_Number, Student_Name,` dynamic sql line if @Exam_Type is not null.

```
ALTER Proc GetExamResults (@Course_Id varchar(100), @Semester varchar(10), @Exam_Type varchar(50) = null)
as
begin
    declare @subjname varchar(100)  
    declare @subjects varchar(7000)  
    declare @subjectsselection varchar(7000)  
    declare @SumSelection varchar(7000)  
    declare @NoOfSubjects int
    set @NoOfSubjects = 0

    set @subjects = ''  
    set @subjectsselection = '' 
    set @SumSelection = ''

    DECLARE subject_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT distinct Subject_Name FROM Exam_Result where course_id = @Course_Id And Semester = @Semester And (@Exam_Type is null OR @Exam_Type = Exam_Type)

    OPEN subject_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
    INTO @subjname  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        set @subjects = @subjects + '[' + @subjname + '],'  
        set @subjectsselection = @subjectsselection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0)) As [' + @subjname + '],' 
        set @SumSelection = @SumSelection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0))+' 

        set @NoOfSubjects = @NoOfSubjects + 1

        FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
        INTO @subjname  
    End  
    CLOSE subject_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE subject_cursor;  

    select @subjects = LEFT(@subjects, LEN(@subjects) - 1)  
    select @subjectsselection = LEFT(@subjectsselection, LEN(@subjectsselection) - 1)  
    select @SumSelection = LEFT(@SumSelection, LEN(@SumSelection) - 1)  

    print @subjects  
    print @subjectsselection  
    print @SumSelection

    declare @query nvarchar(4000)  

    set @query = 'select S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, ' + @subjectsselection + ',' 
    set @query = @query + 'Exam_Type,' + @SumSelection + ' As Grand_Total, '
    set @query = @query + '(' + @SumSelection + ')' + '/' + convert(varchar(10),@NoOfSubjects) + ' As Avg'
    set @query = @query + ' From '  
    set @query = @query + '(select Enroll_Number, Student_Name, Course_Id, Semester, Subject_Name, MarksObtained, Exam_Type from Exam_Result ' + (case when @Exam_Type is null then '' else ' Where Exam_Type =''' + @Exam_Type + '''' end) + ' ) ps '  
    set @query = @query + ' pivot(sum(MarksObtained) for Subject_Name in (' + @subjects + ')) as pvt'  
    set @query = @query + ' inner join Stud_Info S on S.Enroll_Number = pvt.Enroll_Number '
    set @query = @query + ' where pvt.Course_Id = ''' + @Course_Id + ''' and pvt.Semester = ''' + @Semester + ''''
    set @query = @query + ' group by S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, Exam_Type'
    print @query
    exec sp_executesql @query  
end
```

Comment: Nikola Markovinovic - it works fine while i passed parameter with **Exam_Type** but it gives error while not passing 3rd parameter **Exam_Type**....**Error** something like **Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure ExamResult, Line 0
Procedure or function 'ExamResult' expects parameter '@Exam_Type', which was not supplied.
**

Comment: @mack28 Did you forget to put `= null` in parameter list for @Exam_type? I've tested the procedure both ways.

Comment: Nikola Markovinovic - yes, i forgot to add **(@Exam_Type is null OR @Exam_Type = Exam_Type)** this line....thanks..it works